# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send'of undefined | Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

```js
 let generalChannel = client.channels.cache.get("739065709132382261")
 generalChannel.send("Hello!")
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that the channel ID is correct?

Comment: error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: guild is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Discord Bot\Mada_bot.js:12:9)-------------------------------------------------MY code Is      client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log(guild.name);
    });
        guild.channels.forEach((channel) => {
            console.log(` - ${channel.name} $(channel.type) $channel.id}`)
        })
        //General channel id: 739065709132382261

    }) 
    let generalChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === general)

Comment: create a new question if you have completely new code

Answer (score 0):

`client.channels.cache.get` needs to be specified with channel's name, as far as I know. So, instead of `let generalChannel = client.channel.cache.get("ID")`, try using `let generalChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "Name of the channel")`

Comment: Saying that `client.channels.cache.get` needs to be a channels name, is inaccurate information.

Comment: I'm used to `client.channel.cache.find`, my mind wasn't working well when I was writting the comment and thought they were the same, lol. Sorry for that

Comment: I got anothe error now:--------ReferenceError: guild is not defined
    at Client

Comment: As Levi told you on another comment, could you provide us the whole code? It's probably something that isn't related to this specific part of the code